# How to delete KDE activity

Tags: kde

I don't know why, but I made an activity.

[image]

Anyway, how can I delete it?

Comment: I tried to find clear instructions for deleting an activity in recent versions of KDE but couldn't. I found something but the reply is a bit cryptic: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=140444

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned your OS details but on Kubuntu 16.04 with kubuntu-backports installed to have KDE Plasma 5.8.7, you can open "System Settings", "Desktop Behavior", "Activities". See https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?t=72006 for how to install kubuntu-backports: even though the link mentions Zesty Zapus, the procedure is the same for Xenial.

As the image shows, there's a trash icon that would enable you to delete an activity. But don't try to delete the "Default"!

[image: Activities - System Settings]

Comment: Thanks to the answer but I don't have "Default" activity in my setting. I have only "a" activity, and I cannot delete "a" activity.

Comment: And also I didn't changed any settings about "Activities".

Comment: You still haven't mentioned the version of Kubuntu or whatever it is you're using. Things change: features and settings get added or removed.